# Display views based on the count of data coming from webservice in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on generating dynamic views based on the total questions coming from the server. And each question should have an edittext field where the user can answer that question. Each question should use a layout like viewpager. At the end I have to submit all the answers to the server. Can anyone help me getting this out.

Comment: what you tried so far ? Create the views dynamically (programatically ) and achive your expected result

Comment: It sounds like your not really familiar with Android programming. Please come back with a more precise question associated with a code sample or at least an explained problem.

Comment: The thing is simple, i want to make a quiz app, and the questions will come from server.we can go to next question by swiping right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey as you haven't show your code or any design what I understand I will explain you solution here.

1. From server you get list of question so you have count of number of questions.
2. Now by using count loop create dynamic View Pager from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager)
3. Once your Viewpager is ready then In same loop you can create dynamic EditText from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510863/android-create-edittext-on-runtime)
4. Once you done with about you may have Submit button on Top then Tap on It and write Async Call.

Hope this helps If you need more clarification then share your code or your concept design I have confusion in your question for ViewPager like design.